# C# ListView - control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview, controls

How can I select an entire row of a ListView control in Details view-mode?

Or alternatively, how can I select a row in a ListView by clicking on any subItem?

Comment: or Winforms? Since people still, you know, use it

Comment: VS2005 Plain Windows Application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [FullRowSelect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.fullrowselect.aspx) Property is what you are looking for to highlight the entire row when it is selected.

Answer (score 2):

use property FullRowSelect of ListView

Answer (score 2):

I might be missing the point but does setting `FullRowSelect` to `true` on the `ListView` achieve what you want?